# how to get words from html in an array using php?

Tags: php, html

```
<?php
$html = file_get_contents('http://hypermedia.ids-mannheim.de/');
?>
```

this code returns me the html of the website in a string. How do I separate the string into different words? After getting the individual words in an array I would like to detect which one is in German...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$words = explode(' ', strip_tags($html));
```

or

```
$words = preg_split("/[\s,]+/", strip_tags($html));
```

The second one will consider not just the space character as a delimiter, but tabs and commas as well.

Comment: cool, the words are done, but how do I lose certain special characters from the words like ®  in grammis®? I want only A-Z and a-z and ä to make up the words.

Answer (score 0):

work with a regex, something like this

```
#([\w]+)#i
```

A code example:

```
if(preg_match_all('#([\w]+)\b#i', $text, $matches)) {
    foreach($matches[1] as $key => $word) {
        echo $word."\n";
    }
}
```

Then you have to compare each with some kind of dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to separate your problem into steps.
First parse your returned html string to find which part is html tags and structure. You can use [DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) for such purpose.

Then, you can separate your innerHTML data from tags and split innerHTML text into tokens to obtain an array. Dunno the best way but a simple array regex split can do the job.

The interesting part of finding german words, could be done matching your wordlist against a dictionary, again using arrays or maps.. or, better, using a DB (SQLlite maybe could be better than a *real* rdbms like mysql)..